# Definition of level covers in a moduli space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, jacobian, abelian-varieties

I'm studying Samuel Grushevsky'paper, The Schottky Problem, and there is a definition that I do not understand, **level covers**, in the paper he defines two spaces
$\mathcal{A}_g(l)$ and $\mathcal{A}_g(l,2l)$.

Do you know where I can find theory about that?

Thank you.

[image]